# DirectX debugging

Tags: debugging, visualization

Any suggestions how can I track visual changes performed through an win32 process? I have almost no knowledge how they are done. I'm currently debugging an application which uses it's own custom FONT files to drawn letters, however I can only trace the drawing at a very high-level and can't connect it with DirectX API for example. I'm also curios if it is possible to use the VS new [Graphics Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708963.aspx) to attach into a running process.

Any clues about how to achieve this? I have no source code of the target application and I'm using IDA Pro + API Monitor.

I'm especially interested in drawing letters.